# Windows.Form Combobox is not in sync with the dropdown list in bigger monitors

Tags: winforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG7q5.png)The dropdownlist and the combo box doesn't sync in bigger screens Works perfectly fine with smaller screens. When I click on the drop down the list appears somewhere else on the screen as higlighted. In smaller screens works fine as shown in this image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPsDi.png)

```
 this.m_ComboBoxType.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.m_ComboBoxType.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.m_ComboBoxType.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.m_ComboBoxType.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(89, 26);
        this.m_ComboBoxType.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        this.m_ComboBoxType.Name = "m_ComboBoxType";
        this.m_ComboBoxType.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(199, 24);
        this.m_ComboBoxType.Sorted = true;
        this.m_ComboBoxType.TabIndex = 3;
        this.m_ComboBoxType.SelectionChangeCommitted += new System.EventHandler(this.m_ComboBoxType_SelectionChangeCommitted);
```

Enabling the compatibity property "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" of the application solved the problem. But how do I do it from the C# application code.
Adding below code in the manifest solves issue. But this makes the application blurry in the laptop.

```
<asmv3:application>
 <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2017/WindowsSettings">
   <gdiScaling>true</gdiScaling>
 </asmv3:windowsSettings>
```

Please me with the exact code for the below settings in the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XBfC.png)
Setting property to application, only solves my problem. Setting it to system and system advanced creates issue in smaller screen. How do I set it to application using code.

Comment: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103).

Comment: You should probably fix the image, which is not displaying. Also, consider explaining the problem more clearly, including some context, then say what you've tried.